Memory Leak in Asynchronous HTTP Requests with aiohttp in Django
I'm encountering a memory leak issue in my Django application that utilizes aiohttp for making asynchronous HTTP requests. I've set up a function to fetch data from a REST API, but despite my attempts to manage memory effectively, I'm observing a significant increase in memory usage with each batch of requests processed.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
    import logging
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    import aiohttp
    import asyncio
    import gc
    from memory_profiler import profile

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    async def fetch(session, url):
        async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            return await response.json()

    @profile
    async def main():
        URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
        REQUEST_COUNT = 1000
        CONCURRENT_LIMIT = 50  
        BATCH_SIZE = 100

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)) as session:
            semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(CONCURRENT_LIMIT)

            async def fetch_with_limit():
                async with semaphore:
                    return await fetch(session, URL)

            for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
                tasks = [fetch_with_limit() for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
                results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
                tasks.clear()

        await session.close()
        del session
        gc.collect()
        return

    async def test_httpx_view(request):
        asyncio.create_task(main())
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'Success'}, status=200)

Profiling Results
I've run memory profiling on the main() function, and the results indicate a significant memory increment with each batch processed:

    Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
    =============================================================
    288    171.8 MiB    171.8 MiB           1   @profile
    289                                         async def main():
    290    171.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    291    171.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       REQUEST_COUNT = 1000
    292    171.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       CONCURRENT_LIMIT = 50  
    293    171.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       BATCH_SIZE = 100
    294                                         
    295                                             # Initialize local session to ensure closure after each batch
    296    171.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
    297    171.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)
    298    171.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       ) as session:
    299    171.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(CONCURRENT_LIMIT)
    300                                         
    301    191.0 MiB    -18.9 MiB        1001           async def fetch_with_limit():
    302    191.0 MiB    -14.6 MiB        1500               async with semaphore:
    303    191.0 MiB   -101.7 MiB        5191                   return await fetch(session, URL)
    304                                         
    305    191.0 MiB      0.0 MiB          12           for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
    306    191.0 MiB      0.0 MiB        1030               tasks = [fetch_with_limit() for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
    307    191.0 MiB     -0.3 MiB          20               results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    308                                         
    309                                                     # Here you could process the results from each batch if needed
    310    191.0 MiB      0.0 MiB          10               logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
    311                                         
    312                                                     # Clean up after each batch
    313    191.0 MiB      0.0 MiB          10               tasks.clear()
    314                                         
    315    191.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       await session.close()
    316    191.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       del session
    317    191.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
    318    191.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return


    INFO:     127.0.0.1:41392 - "GET /test_aiohttp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

    Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
    =============================================================
    288    190.8 MiB    190.8 MiB           1   @profile
    289                                         async def main():
    290    190.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    291    190.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       REQUEST_COUNT = 1000
    292    190.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       CONCURRENT_LIMIT = 50  
    293    190.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       BATCH_SIZE = 100
    294                                         
    295                                             # Initialize local session to ensure closure after each batch
    296    190.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
    297    190.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)
    298    190.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       ) as session:
    299    190.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(CONCURRENT_LIMIT)
    300                                         
    301    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB        1001           async def fetch_with_limit():
    302    191.4 MiB      0.1 MiB        1500               async with semaphore:
    303    191.4 MiB      0.5 MiB        5134                   return await fetch(session, URL)
    304                                         
    305    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB          12           for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
    306    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB        1030               tasks = [fetch_with_limit() for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
    307    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB          20               results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    308                                         
    309                                                     # Here you could process the results from each batch if needed
    310    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB          10               logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
    311                                         
    312                                                     # Clean up after each batch
    313    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB          10               tasks.clear()
    314                                         
    315    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       await session.close()
    316    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       del session
    317    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
    318    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return


    INFO:     127.0.0.1:40942 - "GET /test_aiohttp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
    INFO:     127.0.0.1:40942 - "GET /test_aiohttp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

    Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
    =============================================================
    288    191.4 MiB    191.4 MiB           2   @profile
    289                                         async def main():
    290    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    291    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       REQUEST_COUNT = 1000
    292    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       CONCURRENT_LIMIT = 50  
    293    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       BATCH_SIZE = 100
    294                                         
    295                                             # Initialize local session to ensure closure after each batch
    296    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           4       async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
    297    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           2           connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)
    298    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       ) as session:
    299    191.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           2           semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(CONCURRENT_LIMIT)
    300                                         
    301    206.5 MiB    -72.7 MiB        1902           async def fetch_with_limit():
    302    206.5 MiB   -107.7 MiB        2850               async with semaphore:
    303    206.5 MiB   -364.5 MiB        9791                   return await fetch(session, URL)
    304                                         
    305    206.5 MiB     -0.7 MiB          21           for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
    306    206.5 MiB    -74.8 MiB        1957               tasks = [fetch_with_limit() for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
    307    206.5 MiB     -1.5 MiB          37               results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    308                                         
    309                                                     # Here you could process the results from each batch if needed
    310    206.5 MiB     -0.7 MiB          18               logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
    311                                         
    312                                                     # Clean up after each batch
    313    206.5 MiB     -0.7 MiB          18               tasks.clear()
    314                                         
    315    206.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       await session.close()
    316    206.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       del session
    317    206.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
    318    206.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return

Observations
The memory usage starts at approximately 171.8 MiB but increases with every batch processed.
I have included garbage collection explicitly, yet memory usage continues to rise.
The async with statement ensures that the ClientSession is closed after each batch, but it seems not to be effectively freeing memory.
Updated Code
URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
REQUEST_COUNT = 1000
CONCURRENT_LIMIT = 50
BATCH_SIZE = 100

 
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(CONCURRENT_LIMIT)


async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        return await response.json()


async def fetch_with_limit(session):
    async with semaphore:
        return await fetch(session, URL)

@profile
async def main():
     
    gc.collect()
    
     
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)) as session:
         
        for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
             
            tasks = [fetch_with_limit(session) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
            results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)   
            logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
            
             
            tasks.clear()
            del results
            gc.collect()

     
    gc.collect()

 
async def test_httpx_view(request):
    asyncio.create_task(main())
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'Success'}, status=200)

Observations for Updated Code
I applied the idea suggested by @gdub here of moving the semaphore, constant and fetch_with_limit function to the main part of the code (global scope) to avoid their repeated creation and, as you claim, guaranteed memory leak. Also added gc.collect() functions to the beginning and end of main. Then for the first requests the memory usage remains +- stable, around 190 MB of memory.
When running successive requests one after another I notice that the memory increases significantly, indicating that some objects may still not be released immediately, possibly due to caching inside aiohttp or limitations in Python's asynchronous resource management.
Interestingly, I observe that after running several successive request cycles, running one subsequent request causes the memory to return closer to its original state.
Profiling Results for Updated Code
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
  1127    188.4 MiB    188.4 MiB           1   @profile
  1128                                         async def main():
  1129                                             
  1130    188.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
  1131                                             
  1132                                             
  1133    188.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)) as session:
  1134                                                 
  1135    199.8 MiB      0.0 MiB          30           for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
  1136                                                     
  1137    199.8 MiB      0.0 MiB        2884               tasks = [fetch_with_limit(session) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
  1138    199.8 MiB     11.4 MiB          56               results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks) 
  1139    199.8 MiB      0.0 MiB          28               logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
  1140                                                     
  1141                                                     
  1142    199.8 MiB      0.0 MiB          28               tasks.clear()
  1143    199.8 MiB      0.0 MiB          28               del results
  1144    199.8 MiB      0.0 MiB          28               gc.collect()
  1145                                         
  1146                                            
  1147    199.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()


INFO:     127.0.0.1:41952 - "GET /test_aiohttp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:41952 - "GET /test_aiohttp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:41952 - "GET /test_aiohttp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:41952 - "GET /test_aiohttp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:41952 - "GET /test_aiohttp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:41952 - "GET /test_aiohttp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
  1127    199.2 MiB    199.7 MiB           6   @profile
  1128                                         async def main():
  1129                                             
  1130    199.2 MiB    -10.0 MiB           6       gc.collect()
  1131                                             
  1132                                             
  1133    199.2 MiB     -1.2 MiB           6       async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)) as session:
  1134                                                 
  1135    206.7 MiB     -2.5 MiB          49           for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
  1136                                                     
  1137    206.7 MiB   -257.4 MiB        4841               tasks = [fetch_with_limit(session) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
  1138    206.7 MiB      3.6 MiB          89               results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  
  1139    206.7 MiB     -1.2 MiB          42               logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
  1140                                                     
  1141                                                     
  1142    206.7 MiB     -1.2 MiB          42               tasks.clear()
  1143    206.7 MiB     -1.2 MiB          42               del results
  1144    206.7 MiB     -1.2 MiB          42               gc.collect()
  1145                                         
  1146                                             
  1147    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()


Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
  1127    199.2 MiB    198.9 MiB           5   @profile
  1128                                         async def main():
  1129                                             
  1130    199.2 MiB     -0.2 MiB           5       gc.collect()
  1131                                             
  1132                                             
  1133    199.2 MiB     -0.2 MiB           5       async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)) as session:
  1134                                                 
  1135    206.7 MiB     -0.2 MiB          47           for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
  1136                                                     
  1137    206.7 MiB    -25.6 MiB        4635               tasks = [fetch_with_limit(session) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
  1138    206.7 MiB      7.1 MiB          86               results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  
  1139    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          41               logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
  1140                                                     
  1141                                                     
  1142    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          41               tasks.clear()
  1143    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          41               del results
  1144    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          41               gc.collect()
  1145                                         
  1146                                             
  1147    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()


Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
  1127    199.2 MiB    198.9 MiB           4   @profile
  1128                                         async def main():
  1129                                             
  1130    199.2 MiB     -0.2 MiB           4       gc.collect()
  1131                                             
  1132                                             
  1133    199.2 MiB     -0.2 MiB           4       async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)) as session:
  1134                                                 
  1135    206.7 MiB     -0.2 MiB          44           for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
  1136                                                     
  1137    206.7 MiB    -25.6 MiB        4326               tasks = [fetch_with_limit(session) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
  1138    206.7 MiB      7.1 MiB          81               results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks) 
  1139    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          39               logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
  1140                                                     
  1141                                                     
  1142    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          39               tasks.clear()
  1143    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          39               del results
  1144    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          39               gc.collect()
  1145                                         
  1146                                             
  1147    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()


Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
  1127    199.2 MiB    198.9 MiB           3   @profile
  1128                                         async def main():
  1129                                             
  1130    199.2 MiB     -0.2 MiB           3       gc.collect()
  1131                                             
  1132                                             
  1133    199.2 MiB     -0.2 MiB           3       async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)) as session:
  1134                                                 
  1135    206.7 MiB     -0.2 MiB          42           for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
  1136                                                     
  1137    206.7 MiB    -25.6 MiB        4120               tasks = [fetch_with_limit(session) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
  1138    206.7 MiB      7.1 MiB          78               results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  
  1139    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          38               logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
  1140                                                     
  1141                                                     
  1142    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          38               tasks.clear()
  1143    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          38               del results
  1144    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          38               gc.collect()
  1145                                         
  1146                                             
  1147    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()


Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
  1127    199.2 MiB    199.2 MiB           1   @profile
  1128                                         async def main():
  1129                                             
  1130    199.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
  1131                                             
  1132                                             
  1133    199.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)) as session:
  1134                                                 
  1135    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          38           for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
  1136                                                     
  1137    206.7 MiB      0.1 MiB        3708               tasks = [fetch_with_limit(session) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
  1138    206.7 MiB      7.4 MiB          72               results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  
  1139    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          36               logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
  1140                                                     
  1141                                                     
  1142    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          36               tasks.clear()
  1143    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          36               del results
  1144    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          36               gc.collect()
  1145                                         
  1146                                             
  1147    206.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()


Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
  1127    199.2 MiB    198.9 MiB           2   @profile
  1128                                         async def main():
  1129                                             
  1130    199.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       gc.collect()
  1131                                             
  1132                                             
  1133    199.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)) as session:
  1134                                                 
  1135    206.7 MiB     -4.5 MiB          43           for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
  1136                                                     
  1137    206.7 MiB      0.1 MiB        4017               tasks = [fetch_with_limit(session) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
  1138    206.7 MiB      6.4 MiB          78               results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  
  1139    206.7 MiB     -1.2 MiB          39               logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
  1140                                                     
  1141                                                     
  1142    206.7 MiB     -1.2 MiB          39               tasks.clear()
  1143    206.7 MiB     -1.2 MiB          39               del results
  1144    206.7 MiB     -1.2 MiB          39               gc.collect()
  1145                                         
  1146                                             
  1147    206.7 MiB     -3.5 MiB           2       gc.collect()


INFO:     127.0.0.1:33410 - "GET /test_aiohttp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK


Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
  1127    202.4 MiB    202.4 MiB           1   @profile
  1128                                         async def main():
  1129                                             
  1130    199.7 MiB     -2.8 MiB           1       gc.collect()
  1131                                             
  1132                                             
  1133    199.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, ttl_dns_cache=10)) as session:
  1134                                                 
  1135    199.7 MiB    -14.0 MiB          12           for i in range(0, REQUEST_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE):
  1136                                                     
  1137    199.7 MiB  -1090.4 MiB        1030               tasks = [fetch_with_limit(session) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]
  1138    199.7 MiB    -23.8 MiB          20               results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  
  1139    199.5 MiB    -13.2 MiB          10               logger.info(f"Batch {i // BATCH_SIZE + 1} completed with {len(results)} responses.")
  1140                                                     
  1141                                                     
  1142    199.5 MiB    -11.1 MiB          10               tasks.clear()
  1143    199.5 MiB    -11.1 MiB          10               del results
  1144    199.5 MiB    -11.1 MiB          10               gc.collect()
  1145                                         
  1146                                             
  1147    196.8 MiB     -2.9 MiB           1       gc.collect()

Additional Information
I've tried using Python versions 3.12.3, 3.10.15, and 3.9.2. For Python 3.9.2, the following library versions are used:
aiohttp: Version 3.10.10
multidict: Version 6.1.0
yarl: Version 1.17.1
async_timeout: Version 4.0.3
Question
What might be causing the memory leak in this setup?
Are there any additional steps I can take to ensure proper memory management with aiohttp in an asynchronous context?
How can I optimize the code to avoid significant memory growth when running successive requests? Perhaps there is a more efficient way to manage resource release within an asynchronous cycle?


Move data assigned only once like semaphore and constants to the main body.
Also move fetch_with_limit to the main body. Every time you run main it creates a new fetch_with_limit which is never deleted. I'm guessing that's why you see a jump at that point.
I can't provide a concrete rationale, but programmer intuition tells me you should gc.collect() at the start and end of the function for the best understanding of why memory isn't being released.

EDIT:
If the main goal here is using the least amount of memory possible, then you do NOT want to use asyncio. Given the pattern of using the results for a second then deleting, then it uses more memory to download multiple things at once. In serial fashion you discard all the old data before fetching the next

Thanks for the suggestions.
I moved the semaphore, constants, and fetch_with_limit to the global scope to avoid re-creation.
However, I noticed that the memory increases significantly during successive requests, suggesting that some objects are not released immediately - possibly due to aiohttp caching or Python's asynchronous resource management. After a few request cycles, running a single request reduces the memory slightly closer to its original state.
How can I better manage memory growth between successive requests?

Use TaskGroups to clean up your async tasks in test_httpx_view

FYI, django is now supporting asynchronous views...
